# Is there a word for a non-null set?

Tags: measure-theory

Say I'm in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I want to talk about a subset which has "area", i.e. it contains some open disk of some length. Is there a word for this kind of set? If I'm not mistaken, this set can be described as "not a null subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$" or "not a measure zero subset". But I want to know if there's a concise terminology for a set with area.

Note that this set I've described is not necessarily measurable, it just contains some area. But if there is a word that is restricted to sets that are measurable, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: I'd usually say "a set of positive measure".

Comment: @ElchananSolomon the OP mentioned specifically that the set does not need to be measurable.

Comment: @PierreCarre, I missed that, thanks for pointing that out! There is a notion of a positive set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_sets), so maybe "strictly positive set"?

Comment: Containing a disk is not the same as having positive measure. Containing a disk means having non-void (or non-empty) interior.

Comment: If you want "not measure zero", then "positive outer measure" is the appropriate term. This is widely used when non-measurable sets are included, such as when measure zero is used as a "smallness notion" in contexts where measurability/non-measurability is of secondary importance. But see the comment by @PhoemueX, as your question seems to conflate two different properties.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Is it correct/common to describe such sets as "having area"? That might imply measurability, so how about "containing area"?

Comment: I would avoid the word "area", since it is more of a natural language term than a precisely defined mathematical term, at least unless the context is known. For example, "area" is fine when talking about polygons, circles, and even more exotic curves in ordinary synthetic and analytic geometry. But once you are in the realm in which non-measurable sets could arise, I would not use the word "area" (unless it is explicitly defined).